# Is this JSON structure an array or an object?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse JSON using JavaScript, but I can't figure out how to iterate over this structure because I can't determine whether this is an array, an object, or an object containing an array. Here is the code:

```
{
"noun":
    {
    "syn":
    ["trial","trial run","tryout","mental test","mental testing","psychometric        
    test","examination","exam","run","attempt","communicating","communication","cover","covering","effort","endeavor","endeavour","experiment","experimentation","mental measurement","natural covering","try"]
    },
"verb":
    {
    "syn":["prove","try","try out","examine","essay","screen","quiz","ascertain","be","check","determine","evaluate","find out","judge","learn","pass judgment","score","see","submit","take","undergo","watch"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider learning the basics of JavaScript before using it.

Comment: Hi @squint -- I *am* learning the basics of JavaScript. I'm teaching myself, and I'm doing the best I can. I thought that stackoverflow was a place to ask questions, even if they might be stupid, after making a reasonable attempt to find answers in other places. As someone teaching myself to code, I haven't encountered a lot of meanness in the community--I don't know why you decided to comment with something so discouraging when it looks like by your profile you could have easily answered my question, or chosen to move on. We were all beginners at one point. Please respect that.

Comment: I remember being a beginner. It wasn't that long ago. I was, and am, entirely self-taught. I would read all the material I could get my hands on in order to learn the basics. So stop whining and take my good advice.

Comment: ...Googling "JavaScript Arrays vs Objects", or one of many other similar searches brings to you more information than you could possibly hope for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{}` indicate that the JSON block is an OBJECT. It has two properties: `noun` and `verb`. Each property has a single property named `syn` that is an array (denoted by the `[]`) of strings.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the answer I was looking for.